# Finding the MAX value over a range but if one row is blank, the value for MAX must be blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I want to do a MAX value for the latest date in my data for the "Actual" column, but, say that one cell has no date, I want the MAX (in yellow) to be blank too. Any help would be appreciated!

Data from Table Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following formula, assuming that the "Actual" column is C:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(C2:C8)=0,MAX(C2:C8),"")
```

Or more general:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(range)=0,MAX(range),"")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly when there are some blank cells. But I am now having trouble getting a value for columns which do have all their dates filled in, when I use this formula I get "00/01/1900" as the MAX date whenever it should really be the 19/01/2022 for example

Comment: Do all the cells have the Date format?

Comment: Yes the issue was the format Harry, it is sorted now - thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

*You may use any of these also:*

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C8=""))>0,"",MAX(C2:C85))
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:C8,"")>0,"",MAX(C2:C8))
```

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references as needed.*