# MAX Date with IF function giving too many arguments error message

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I had previously had my question answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1684490/finding-the-max-value-over-a-range-but-if-one-row-is-blank-the-value-for-max-mu) but now I am having an issue with blanks in the spreadsheet, if I highlight the whole column and use the formula over that range, I am given a blank answer for the MAX date which shouldn't be the case as I already have all my dates entered, the problem is the greyed out rows which I do not want to use but any time I try to avoid them I get the error message "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

I have been using the formula :

=IF(COUNTBLANK(range)=0,MAX(range),"")

[[image: They greyed out rows are the issue but I cannot remove them due to other information being on said rows along my sheet1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MAX function with multiple ranges. The first range is compulsory. The others are optional. So your formula will be:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(range)<>0,MAX(range1,range2,range3),"")
```

Comment: The problem with the first one is, I need to highlight the range twice but both ranges are separated in two by the grey line in the middle which I don't want to highlight as that will give me a blank date for the MAX

The second formula I have used before but it isn't correct for this job

Comment: Why do you need to highlight the range twice if you are using the same range?

Comment: Because I need to highlight the section which is above the grey row and then below the grey row but both are in the same column .

From the image it shows me trying it but then I get the "Too many arguments error" and I don't want to highlight the whole column all at once because it sets my MAX date to blank instead of it being 24/02/2022

Comment: So you actually want to know the max of for example A4:A5 and A7:A8?

Comment: Yes basically that but across the whole column so that it gives me 1 date value in the Yellow cell

Comment: @SeOKane See edit.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much Reddy!!